# It takes long time to fetch images (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, image, core-data, fetch, photo

I am a beginner ios developer and i want to create a photo album app. I find some codes from internet and try to learn from there. In the app, when i click an album, it takes so much time for the album's collectionview of images to load. To fetch the images, my code is in ViewWillAppear. Can you help me optimize this code for better performance. If there is more than 10-15 images, this takes so long to load. Thanks in advance and sorry if my English is bad.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Call to the super classes implementation of viewWillAppear
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    /* The Photos are stored in Core Data as an NSSet. */
    NSSet *unorderedPhotos = self.album.photos;
    /* To organize them we use a NSSort descriptor to arrange the photos by date. */
    NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortedPhotos = [unorderedPhotos sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[dateDescriptor]];
    self.photos = [sortedPhotos mutableCopy];

    /* Now that the photos are arranged we reload our CollectionView. */
    [self.collectionView reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are stored in Core Data as raw blocks of data. The data is the same as when you convert `UIImage`s to `NSData`s. This can result very quickly in a LOT of data being stored in your database, which has to be fetched and de-serialised, hence why it can be slow.

In terms of speed, here's a few things you might want to think about and read up on:

1) [File formats](http://users.wfu.edu/matthews/misc/graphics/formats/formats.html): Is Core Data the best option for you? Core Data is a really useful tool, especially for large amounts of repetitive data, but it doesn't excel with large blocks of data like images. Think about saving the images in different formats (png, jpeg, tiff, e.t.c) to get better performance.

2) [Lazy loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading): Do you really need to load ALL your images at once? If you can load, say 5 at a time then you can significantly reduce the amount of data you need to retrieve in one go. E.g. imagine a table that the user is scrolling through with 1000 rows, the table isn't going to load 1000 rows all in one go, it's going to load, just enough to give the user a good experience and no more.

3) [Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html): This is a really useful tool that every developer should know about although you have to be careful when using it because it can cause more problems than it solves. However, the whole idea is to dispatch tasks on background threads that results in much quicker processing times. I won't go into detail here because it's a large topic but well worth knowing about. (If you read the link, look to **dispatch queues**.)

It was quite a general question, so you have quite a general answer but I hope that you'll find what you're looking for. Happy coding!

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think i must learn more to do this app. I learned that storing in the app's directory will be much faster but i dont know how to do it.